# How to validate datepicker date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Good Day!

I'm currently working on validating 2 datepicker which are

Date Received and Date Delivered

My issue is when i choose today's date 12/29/2015 in Date Received and if i choose 1/1/2016 in Date Delivered my validation should accept the 2 dates but it's not working. I thinks it only reading the 12/29 and 1/1 not the year.

Here's my code

```
var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
var datepicker1 = document.getElementById('datepicker1').value;


if (datepicker1 <= datepicker && datepicker1 != "" ) 
{

    alert("Invalid Date Combination!");
    document.getElementById('datepicker').value = "";
    document.getElementById('datepicker1').value = "";
} 


datepicker1 = Date Delivered 
datepicker = Date Received




     HTML 

<div style="float:right; " >
Date Received <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="getDate()" style="width: 135px;" name="sewdatereceived"  required />

Date Delivered <input type="text" id="datepicker1" onchange="getDate()" style="width: 135px;" name="sewdatedelivered" required />
</div>
```

Comment: what library are you using for datepicker?

Comment: Please show your markup and the framework you are using for the datepicker

Comment: What values are assigned to *datepicker* and *datepicker1*? Likely they are strings and you are trying to subtract strings that can't be converted to numbers, so you get *NaN*.

Comment: and are you just comparing strings instead of actual date objects?

Comment: I updated my question please see it on top. Thanks

Comment: Any library is being used for datepicker ? This might help: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r5qq48n5/

Comment: In general terms, you cannot do reliable maths with strings. Just use real Date objects. Depending of your library of choice, you might already have it available or you'll need to convert yourself.